# SQL: Split and Group By date and time

Tags: sql

Part of the table.

| Reg_Date |
| --- |
| 2021-06-18 08:53:19.000 |
| 2021-06-18 08:53:31.000 |
| 2021-06-18 08:53:32.000 |
| 2021-06-18 08:54:57.000 |
| 2021-06-18 08:55:07.000 |

Expected Result

| Reg_Date | Registration_Count |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-06-18 | 43 |
| 2021-06-18 | 23 |
| 2021-06-18 | 2 |
| 2021-06-18 | 65 |
| 2021-06-18 | 7 |

I am trying to count the number of occurrence of the date. The query below is just to indicate the desired result.

```
select split(reg_date,' '), count(reg_date) from dbo.table group by reg_date
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to group by only the dates and not the datetimes

```
select cast(reg_date as date) as Reg_Date, 
       count(*) as Registration_Count
from dbo.table 
group by cast(reg_date as date)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you use SQL Server. In this SQL dialect instead of the split function you should cast the datetime value:

```
cast(reg_date As Date)
```